Using "sort-by" on vuetify3 v-data-table-server
I'm trying to sort a column of my table in Vuetify3.
   <v-data-table-server 
     :items="logs"
     :headers="headers"
     :loading="loading"
     :sort-by="[{ key: 'dateTime', order: 'desc'}]"
     sort-desc
     must-sort
   >

The table header displays an arrow that toggles up and down but doesn't sort the table.
It was working in Vuetify2 using
sort-by="dateTime"

Any ideas?

In server-side data-table you have to listen to update:options event, which contain a sortBy property. Use that value to tell your server to return a sorted array of items. This component will not do the sorting itself.

@IgorMoraru Thanks. I have @update:options="setup". But, I don't know where to include sortBy in it. setup is a function to fetch data from a database.

You'll have to implement the sorting yourself at the database (API) level. For example refactor your fetch data endpoint to accept a sortBy query parameter (if it doesn't already), access it with \/fetch-data?sortBy=${sortBy}`` and do the sorting on the server. Or, include details about your setup function and the fetch data endpoint into the question to get a more focused response (although server-side sorting may well get out of the scope of this question).

@IgorMoraru Can I have more than one @update?

Not sure what do you mean. If you're asking if @update:options can be bound multiple times then no. But you can invoke multiple functions from the same event. Or, do you mean if you can bind to different events like @update:options, @update:model-value, @update:sort-by? If so, then yes.

This looks to work.
<template>
  <v-data-table
    v-model:sort-by="sortBy"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
  ></v-data-table>

  <pre>{{ sortBy }}</pre>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        sortBy: [{ key: 'calories', order: 'asc' }],
        headers: [
          {
            title: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'start',
            sortable: false,
            key: 'name',
          },
          { title: 'Calories', key: 'calories' },
          { title: 'Fat (g)', key: 'fat' },
          { title: 'Carbs (g)', key: 'carbs' },
          { title: 'Protein (g)', key: 'protein' },
          { title: 'Iron (%)', key: 'iron' },
        ],
        desserts: [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 200,
            fat: 6.0,
            carbs: 24,
            protein: 4.0,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
            calories: 200,
            fat: 9.0,
            carbs: 37,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Eclair',
            calories: 300,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 23,
            protein: 6.0,
            iron: '7%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Cupcake',
            calories: 300,
            fat: 3.7,
            carbs: 67,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '8%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Gingerbread',
            calories: 400,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 49,
            protein: 3.9,
            iron: '16%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Jelly bean',
            calories: 400,
            fat: 0.0,
            carbs: 94,
            protein: 0.0,
            iron: '0%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Lollipop',
            calories: 400,
            fat: 0.2,
            carbs: 98,
            protein: 0,
            iron: '2%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Honeycomb',
            calories: 400,
            fat: 3.2,
            carbs: 87,
            protein: 6.5,
            iron: '45%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Donut',
            calories: 500,
            fat: 25.0,
            carbs: 51,
            protein: 4.9,
            iron: '22%',
          },
          {
            name: 'KitKat',
            calories: 500,
            fat: 26.0,
            carbs: 65,
            protein: 7,
            iron: '6%',
          },
        ],
      }
    },
  }
</script>

